# Play doesn't recognise the new configuration filename while using config.resource

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

Everything goes normally if I put the `application.conf` file in the `my_project/conf` folder. I can access the website and query the database as expected.

And then I decided to rename the file application.conf to `dev.conf` file in order to organise the different settings for every environment.

If I put it in root path `d:/dev.conf` and I execute this command:

> [library] $ run -Dconfig.file=d:/dev.conf

This new file is recognised and the configured values are applied as expected. No problem here. But if I put it in the usual folder (`my_project/conf`) and execute this command:

> [library] $ run -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf

the configuration doesn't take effect. I can still access the site but whenever there is an operation involving a database operation it will throw an error below:

> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[Exception: DB plugin is not registered.]]
>   ...
>   ...

The documentation mentioned that `-Dconfig.resource` will automatically grab the intended file in the conf folder. I have already put the file in that folder but somehow my program cannot find it. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do you have only one "dev.conf" file in the "conf" folder? Isn't the application.conf still there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, there is only one `dev.conf` in that folder. The `application.conf` is no longer there. I renamed it to `dev.conf`.

Comment: I've tried the same as you did and the dev.conf was picked up. Try to put some nonsense (asgegegegsv) ad the beginning of dev.conf to see if Play loads it. It should crash if it does.

Comment: Hi Rado, thanks for the suggestion. It's a bug in [Playframework-2.1](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/984). The problem is resolved after I upgrade to the latest version.

I'm closing this issue now.

EDIT:
Not enough reputation to close this issue...

Comment: You can add an answer by yourself and accept it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it is a known [bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/984) in Play 2.1. It has been fixed in the subsequent version. I do not encounter this problem anymore after the framework is upgraded.